# JaVers detects changes in childs if simple property in root object is changed

Tags: java, kotlin, javers

I use Kotlin and I am trying to compare two complex objects (with multiple cycles) with JaVers. These objects use multiple Id-Properties. Therefore I created Id-Classes to have a single Id-Property for every class. In the Id-Classes I also use references to the root objects because I need to use them to create the primary key for my database.

When I compare two objects with a single change in the root object, JaVers should only list one ValueChange. But instead JaVers finds 5 changes instead (NewObject-child, ObjectRemoved-child,ReferenceChanged-child,ListChange-root,ValueChanged-root).
Trying to solve this issue, I updated my equals and hashCode methods for the child objects to check the id of the root object instead of the root object itself when calculating equality ==> `root1.childList == root2.childList` returns `true`.
Any ideas how I can teach JaVers that no child object has changed?

League.kt - root object

```
@Entity
data class League(@EmbeddedId val leagueId: LeagueId? = null,
                  var name: String? = null,
                  var region: String? = null,
                  @OneToMany(cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], orphanRemoval = true)
                  var groups: List<TeamGroup>? = null,
                  @OneToMany(cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], orphanRemoval = true)
                  var matchDays: List<MatchDay>? = null) : Serializable {

    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        if (this === other) return true
        if (javaClass != other?.javaClass) return false

        other as League

        if (leagueId != other.leagueId) return false
        if (name != other.name) return false
        if (region != other.region) return false
        if (groups?.map { it.teamGroupId }?.toSet() != other.groups?.map { it.teamGroupId }?.toSet()) return false
        if (matchDays?.map { it.matchDayId }?.toSet() != other.matchDays?.map { it.matchDayId }?.toSet()) return false

        return true
    }

    override fun hashCode(): Int {
        var result = leagueId?.hashCode() ?: 0
        result = 31 * result + (name?.hashCode() ?: 0)
        result = 31 * result + (region?.hashCode() ?: 0)
        result = 31 * result + (groups?.map { it.teamGroupId }?.toSet()?.hashCode() ?: 0)
        result = 31 * result + (matchDays?.map { it.matchDayId }?.toSet()?.hashCode() ?: 0)
        return result
    }
}
```

LeagueId.kt - root object Id

```
data class LeagueId(val season : String? = null, val abb : String? = null) : Serializable {

    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        if (this === other) return true
        if (javaClass != other?.javaClass) return false

        other as LeagueId

        if (season != other.season) return false
        if (abb != other.abb) return false

        return true
    }

    override fun hashCode(): Int {
        var result = season?.hashCode() ?: 0
        result = 31 * result + (abb?.hashCode() ?: 0)
        return result
    }
}
```

TeamGroup.kt - child object

```
@Entity
data class TeamGroup(@EmbeddedId val teamGroupId: TeamGroupId? = null,
                     val name: String? = null,
                     val mode: String? = null,
                     val tableMode: Int? = null,
                     @OneToMany(mappedBy = "group", cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], orphanRemoval = true)
                     var teams: List<Team>? = null,
                     @OneToMany(mappedBy = "group", cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], orphanRemoval = true)
                     var matches: List<Match>? = null,
                     var remarks: String? = null,
                     @OneToMany(cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], orphanRemoval = true)
                     var rows: List<Row>? = null) : Serializable {

    override fun toString(): String {
        return "TeamGroup(id=${teamGroupId?.id}, nr=${teamGroupId?.nr}, name=$name, mode=$mode, " +
                "tableMode=$tableMode, teams=$teams, matches=$matches, remarks=$remarks, rows=$rows, " +
                "league=${teamGroupId?.league?.leagueId?.season}-${teamGroupId?.league?.leagueId?.abb})"
    }

    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        if (this === other) return true
        if (javaClass != other?.javaClass) return false

        other as TeamGroup

        if (teamGroupId != other.teamGroupId) return false
        if (name != other.name) return false
        if (mode != other.mode) return false
        if (tableMode != other.tableMode) return false
        if (teams?.map{it.id}?.toSet() != other.teams?.map{it.id}?.toSet()) return false
        if (matches?.map{it.matchId}?.toSet() != other.matches?.map{it.matchId}?.toSet()) return false
        if (remarks != other.remarks) return false
        if (rows?.map{it.rowId}?.toSet() != other.rows?.map{it.rowId}?.toSet()) return false

        return true
    }

    override fun hashCode(): Int {
        var result = teamGroupId?.hashCode() ?: 0
        result = 31 * result + (name?.hashCode() ?: 0)
        result = 31 * result + (mode?.hashCode() ?: 0)
        result = 31 * result + (tableMode ?: 0)
        result = 31 * result + (teams?.map{it.id}?.toSet()?.hashCode() ?: 0)
        result = 31 * result + (matches?.map{it.matchId}?.toSet()?.hashCode() ?: 0)
        result = 31 * result + (remarks?.hashCode() ?: 0)
        result = 31 * result + (rows?.map{it.rowId}?.toSet()?.hashCode() ?: 0)
        return result
    }
}
```

TeamGroupId.kt - child object id

```
data class TeamGroupId(@ManyToOne val league: League? = null, val id : Int? = null, val nr : Int? = null) : Serializable {

    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        if (this === other) return true
        if (javaClass != other?.javaClass) return false

        other as TeamGroupId

        if (league?.leagueId != other.league?.leagueId) return false
        if (id != other.id) return false
        if (nr != other.nr) return false

        return true
    }

    override fun hashCode(): Int {
        var result = league?.leagueId?.hashCode() ?: 0
        result = 31 * result + (id ?: 0)
        result = 31 * result + (nr ?: 0)
        return result
    }
}
```

### Update

The problem is the reference to the root object within the id of the child object. If I remove this reference from the id and move to the object itself only one change is detected by JaVers. Due to my data model I am not sure if I can remove this references in every id object. @DiffIgnore is not working within the Id-Property because it is handled as a ValueObject.

Comment: I will take a look

Comment: all test in HockeyComparatorTest are green, could you push a failing test which will show your expectations?

Comment: Tests are failing for current commit https://github.com/alexander-schmidt/ihh/commit/e69b4d78a8f8004692bebd41de24cdc0952b914a. I moved the league-reference from the TeamGroup object back to the TeamGroupId object.

Comment: ok, i see the issue, hold on ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by wrong InstanceId values of your Entities.
Since you have complex objects as Entity IDs, JaVers uses `reflectiveToString()` function to create String representations of IDs.
In your case, it produces really bad results, because you have cycles (ID has a reference to owning Entity).

Fortunately, you can register a custom toString() function using `JaversBuider.registerValueWithCustomToString()` , for example:

```java
@TypeName("Entity")
class Entity {
    @Id Point id
    String data
}

class Point {
    double x
    double y

    String myToString() {
        "("+ (int)x +"," +(int)y + ")"
    }
}

def "should use custom toString function for complex Id"(){
  given:
  Entity entity = new Entity(id: new Point(x: 1/3, y: 4/3))

  when: "default reflectiveToString function"
  def javers = JaversBuilder.javers()
          .build()
  GlobalId id = javers.getTypeMapping(Entity).createIdFromInstance(entity)

  then:
  id.value() == "Entity/0.3333333333,1.3333333333"

  when: "custom toString function"
  javers = JaversBuilder.javers()
          .registerValueWithCustomToString(Point, {it.myToString()})
          .build()
  id = javers.getTypeMapping(Entity).createIdFromInstance(entity)

  then:
  id.value() == "Entity/(0,1)"
}
```

See also updated doc about Entity ID https://javers.org/documentation/domain-configuration/#entity-id

Comment: thanks for the help. Looks like this solves the problem. I changed my data structure to prevent cycles and have less problems with my initial data source. With the new structure I no longer have circles, but I couldn't check if your solution would have done the job.